# Group Similar Items in JSON

Tags: javascript, laravel

Hello I have a collection returned as JSON like this:

```
[
 {
   "quantity": "1",
   "description": "VIP Ticket to Event"
 },
 {
   "quantity": "1",
   "description": "VIP Ticket to Event"
 },
 {
   "quantity": "1",
   "description": "VIP Ticket to Event"
 },
 {
   "quantity": "1",
   "description": "Regular Ticket to Event"
 },
 {
   "quantity": "1",
   "description": "Regular Ticket to Event"
 },
]
```

However I would like to group the similar items together so in the end I have this:

```
[
 {
   "quantity": "3",
   "description": "VIP Tickets to Event"
 },
 {
   "quantity": "2",
   "description": "Regular Tickets to Event"
 }
]
```

It's rather unfortunate but I cannot alter the database structure so the only thing I can do is play around with the results.  What would be a good and efficient way of doing this type of grouping?

This is tagged as both laravel and javascript because I will need to apply the same solution to my front end as well.

Comment: the JSON is generated from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to create a new array with the updated structure - grouped by `description`

```
var grouped = arr.reduce(function(groups, current) {
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        if (groups[i].description == current.description) {
            groups[i].quantity++;
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        groups.push(current);
    }

    return groups;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposal with a temporary object for the reference to the object with the same description.

```js
var array = [{ "quantity": "1", "description": "VIP Ticket to Event" }, { "quantity": "1", "description": "VIP Ticket to Event" }, { "quantity": "1", "description": "VIP Ticket to Event" }, { "quantity": "1", "description": "Regular Ticket to Event" }, { "quantity": "1", "description": "Regular Ticket to Event" }, ],
    grouped = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.description]) {
        this[a.description] = { description: a.description, quantity: 0 };
        grouped.push(this[a.description]);
    }
    this[a.description].quantity += +a.quantity;
}, {});

document.write('<pre> ' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using temporary object

```js
var d = [{ "quantity": "1", "description": "VIP Ticket to Event" }, { "quantity": "1", "description": "VIP Ticket to Event" }, { "quantity": "1", "description": "VIP Ticket to Event" }, { "quantity": "1", "description": "Regular Ticket to Event" }, { "quantity": "1", "description": "Regular Ticket to Event" }]; 

var o = {};

d.forEach(e => o[e.description] = o[e.description] + +e.quantity || +e.quantity);

var r = Object.keys(o).map(e => ({ quantity: o[e], description: e }));
  
document.write('<pre> ' + JSON.stringify(r, 0, 2) + '</pre>');;
```

Answer (score 0):

A different kind of `reduce` where you don't have to iterate over your groups array for every item in input array to check for existing.

Using the reduced value itself as a hashMap to check for duplicate

```
var groupedItemsObj = items.reduce(function(previous, next){
  if(previous[next.description]){
      var updatedQuantity = previous[next.description].quantity +   next.quantity;  
      previous[next.description] = {quantity: updatedQuantity, description: next.description};
  }else{
      previous[next.description] = next;
  }
  return previous;
}, {});
```

And finally using `map` to convert the reduced object to array.

```
var groupedItemsArray = Object.keys(groupedItemsObj).map(function(key){
    return groupedItemsObj[key];
});
```

Check working bin [here](https://jsbin.com/banapicire/edit?js,console). I changed quantity to number. Also changed a few values to 2 to show that its working correctly.